# In C#, I have a subnet bits and need to create a Subnet Mask. How might I do this?

Tags: c#, cisco, subnet

I have a task to complete in C#. I have a Subnet Name: 192.168.10.0/24

I need to find the subnet mask, which would be, in this case, 255.255.255.0.

However, I need to be able to do this in C# WITHOUT the use of the System.Net library (the system I am programming in does not have access to this library).

It seems like the process should be something like:

1) Split the Subnet Name into Number and Bits.

2) Shove the Bits into this that I have found on SO (thanks to [Converting subnet mask "/" notation to Cisco 0.0.0.0 standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151431/converting-subnet-mask-notation-to-cisco-0-0-0-0-standard)):

```
var cidr = 24; // e.g., "/24" 
var zeroBits = 32 - cidr; // the number of zero bits 
var result = uint.MaxValue; // all ones 

// Shift "cidr" and subtract one to create "cidr" one bits; 
//  then move them left the number of zero bits. 
result &= (uint)((((ulong)0x1 << cidr) - 1) << zeroBits); 

// Note that the result is in host order, so we'd have to convert 
//  like this before passing to an IPAddress constructor 
result = (uint)IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder((int)result);
```

However, the problem that I have is that I do not have access to the library that contains the IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder command in the system that I am working. Also, my C# is pretty poor. Does anyone have the C# knowledge to help?

Comment: The code is now:

`uint bitsUInt = Convert.ToUInt32(bits);
uint zeroBits = 32 - bitsUInt;
uint result = uint.MaxValue;
result &= ((((ulong)0x1 << bitsUInt) - 1) << zeroBits);string maskString = result.ToString();`

Sadly, the interpreter says, "Operator '<<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ulong' and 'uint'". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: C/C++ is much more elegant when this close to the bare metal. If you had a choice, that would be a better choice than C#. I'm guessing you don't have a choice here, so nice to see you found an answer, but if performance is a consideration, find a better one.

Answer (score 3):

You could replace that method with the following:

```
static void ToNetworkByteOrder(ref uint n) {
    if(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) {
        // need to flip it
        n = (
            (n << 24)
            |
            ((n & 0xff00) << 8)
            |
            ((n & 0xff0000) >> 8)
            |
            (n >> 24)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm. I have had to re-type the code, as the interpreter seems not to like vars and so I needed to convert everything into uints. The problem that I now have is that it says on the result &= ((((ulong)0x1 << cidr) - 1) << zeroBits); line that Operator '<<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ulong' and 'unit'.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the current code. Are you are using C# 2? The var keyword should be available in VS 2008 or newer. `cidr` and `zeroBits` should be fine as `int` which would be their implicit type using the `var` keyword. `result` will also be fine as it will be a `uint`. All you should have to change is the last line, into: `ToNetworkByteOrder(ref result);`. You can change the method to return the result if you are more comfortable with that or read up on `ref` on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7(v=VS.71).aspx.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler way to get the mask:

```
int mask = -1 << (32 - cidr);
```

You don't need the `Net` assembly to get the bytes in the right order, you can use the `BitConverter` class:

```
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) {
  byte[] parts = BitConverter.GetBytes(mask);
  Array.Reverse(parts);
  mask = BitConverter.ToInt32(parts, 0);
}
```