# How to convert CIDR subnet mask to HEX format?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, hex, netmask

Tell me how to get a value equal to `FFFFFFFE` it turns out to output only `EFFFF` in reverse order and without the first two characters of `FF`

Source Code: [Converting subnet mask “/” notation to Cisco 0.0.0.0 standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3152101/7549532)

```
var cidr = 23;
var zeroBits = 32 - cidr;
var result = uint.MaxValue;

result &= (uint)((((ulong)0x1 << cidr) - 1) << zeroBits);
result = (uint)IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder((int)result);

textBoxHex.Text = result.ToString("X");
```

Comment: More related to your problem (i guess): What do you think `IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder` does?

Comment: @elgonzo then I get a value with two zeros `FFFFFE00`

Comment: Yes, that is the result you get when setting the lower 9 bits to zero (because you do `zeroBits = 32 - cidr`, with _cidr_ being 23). If you don't want the lower 9 bits being zero, then don't zero out the lower 9 bits, i guess. Look at the bit representation for `FFFFFFFE` (your desired subnet mask). How many zero bits would there be on the right side, and thus, what should the value of the `zeroBits` variable be, then? Then also look at how many 1 (one) bits you would have in the subnet mask, thus what should the value of `cidr` be?

Comment: By the way, i accidentally deleted my first comment. I wanted to edit it, but in my infinite stupidity i aimed for the delete button. I repreat it here in short form:  The whole bit-shifting thing in your code example can be reduced to `int result = -1 << zeroBits`. Due to `zeroBits = 32 - cidr;` any possible resulting 32-bit value of the overly complicated bit-shift operation in your question can only be (in order from MSB to LSB) a sequence of zero or more 1-bits followed by 0-bits down to the LSB. Which is exactly the same of what `int result = -1 << zeroBits` does...

Comment: Yes, you are right, this code was intended to get a network mask, not hex values `FFFFFFFE` = `mask 255.255.254.0` = `mask sidr /23` I will try to decide on your advice, thank!

Comment: "_FFFFFFFE = mask 255.255.254.0 = mask sidr /23_" No. That is not true. Well, it is true that "_mask 255.255.254.0 = cidr /23_", but "_FFFFFFFE = mask 255.255.254.0_" is not true at all. How did you end up with believing that the hexadecimal value/representation of the subnet mask 255.255.254.0 would be FFFFFFFE?

Comment: Thank you for your attentiveness, I rested on the wrong value and therefore nothing worked, here is a list of correct values: https://www.pawprint.net/designresources/netmask-converter.php correct value for `/23 = 255.255.254.0 = 0xfffffe00`

Comment: Yeah, and FFFFFE00 is exactly the result value you got for /23 CIDR... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution, using the [BitVector32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.-ctor) class to create the bit array from the length in bits of the net mask.

The bit mask returned by `BitVector32` would be enough, if you just want to print the Hex representation.
Let's assume you also want to represent the address in `IPV4` format.  In this case, the net mask is of course inverted. To convert it to a valid `IpAddress`, we need to invert the bytes order.

[`IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.hosttonetworkorder) won't directly convert to network byte order the value returned by the `BitVector32.Data` property.
We can use [BitConverter.GetBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes) and `Array.Reverse()` or LINQ's `.Reverse()` method to do the same thing.

This is all that's needed:

```
int cidr = 23;
var bits = new BitVector32(-1 << (32 - cidr));
```

To return the HEX representation of the bit mask, just convert it to string specifying the Hex format:
[Formatting Types in .NET (MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
Console.WriteLine(bits.Data.ToString("X2"));
=> FFFFFE00
```

To transform it into an `IpAddress` format, if needed:

```
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)bits.Data);
var netMask = new IPAddress(bytes.Reverse().ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(netMask); 
=> 255.255.254.0
```

Comment: Thank! Your converter to string helped a lot `(bits.Data.ToString("X2")` but don't understand why "X2". Grateful for your time spent writing a lot of options!

Comment: `X` and `x =>` Convert to Hex string in uppercase or lowercase: `15.ToString("X") => F`, `15.ToString("x") => f`. `X2` or `x2` => all value represented with 2 symbols: `15.ToString("X2") => 0F` and not just `F`.

Comment: With your help now it is possible to make lower case letters https://i.stack.imgur.com/86H3t.png